# Hide calendar icon in date-type HTML input on Firefox

Tags: html, css

The problem is simple.

```html
<input type="date />
```

Looks like this on Firefox (desktop and mobile):

[image: date input on firefox]

The internet only suggests a solution for Chrome:

```css
input {
  appearance: none;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
}

input[type="date"]::-webkit-inner-spin-button,
input[type="date"]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
    display: none;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

This does indeed work on Chrome, but not on Firefox.
Nothing I've tried works on Firefox.
I am wondering if it's even possible. I want to hide the calendar icon.
I am aware that on desktop, clicking the calendar is the only way to bring up the date picker. This is not an issue as it is a mobile app.

Comment: I don't think it can be done in firefox. You could wrap the input in a div then use the ::before pseudo element to hide the icon but it's less than ideal.

Answer (score 1):

One way you could do it is to overlay a text input box on top of the date picker then use the [showPicker()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLInputElement/showPicker) method to trigger the date picker dialog box. Use the `change` event to reflect any changes in the date input to the text input. I've not formatted the date but you can use the [Intl.DateTimeFormat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat) object to make the date locale friendly.

Just a note: This won't work on codepen or on the snippet editor due to security reasons so to test it you'll have to drop it onto localhost or your development environment.

```js
const textInput = document.querySelector('.datepicker input[type="text"]');
const dateInput = document.querySelector('.datepicker input[type="date"]');
textInput.addEventListener('focus', (e) => {
  dateInput.showPicker();
});
dateInput.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
  textInput.value = dateInput.value; //Use Intl API to format the date if you want.
});
```

```css
.datepicker {
  width: 8rem;
  position: relative;
}

.datepicker input {
  width: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.datepicker input[type='date'] {
  position: absolute;
  inset: 0;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class='datepicker'>
  <input type=text placeholder='yyyy/mm/dd'>
  <input type=date>
</div>
```

Comment: The UX is not perfect here because the user then needs to manually enter the . or /

Answer (score 1):

Method to hide the native datepicker icon which works in Chrome and Firefox.

**Chrome**

The native ::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator is used

**Non webkit Browser like Firefox**

I simply added an after element on the wrapper as an overlay to hide the native icon. This overlay is not used on chrome.

**Other solutions I tried on Firefox**

- Overwritng the shadow DOM of the datepicker icon -> Deep selector did not work
- Using an pseudo after element on input instead of the wrapper -> Did only work on chrome but not in firefox

```css
.date-input-wrapper {
  width: fit-content;
}

input {
  width: 100%;
}

input[type=date]::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator {
  visibility: hidden;
}

.date-input-wrapper {
  position: relative;
}

.date-input-wrapper::after {
  display: none;
  width: 17px;
  height: 16px;
  background: red;
  /* background: white; */
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  right: 0px;
  top: 2px;
}

@supports not selector(::-webkit-calendar-picker-indicator) {
  .date-input-wrapper::before {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="date-input-wrapper">
  <input type="date">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found that the easiest way was to just use `<input type="text">` instead of `<input type="date">`

I guess its per use case, but we were firing our own date picker when the user interacted with the  so this solution worked for us. You can also add your own icon as well.

```
<input type="text">
```

Comment: Yeah this seems to be the common approach in most UI libraries as well.

Comment: Solution does not help when I want to use the native . or / on the date input